Failed to fetch armhf packages
I use Ubuntu 22.04. When I run sudo apt update I am getting the following error messages:
Err:36 http://mirror.dc.uz/ubuntu jammy-security/main armhf Packages             
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.212.89.107 80]
Ign:46 http://mirror.dc.uz/ubuntu jammy-security/restricted armhf Packages     
Ign:47 http://mirror.dc.uz/ubuntu jammy-security/universe armhf Packages       
Ign:48 http://mirror.dc.uz/ubuntu jammy-security/multiverse armhf Packages     
E: Failed to fetch http://mirror.dc.uz/ubuntu/dists/jammy/main/binary-armhf/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.212.89.107 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://mirror.dc.uz/ubuntu/dists/jammy-updates/main/binary-armhf/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.212.89.107 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://mirror.dc.uz/ubuntu/dists/jammy-backports/main/binary-armhf/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.212.89.107 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://mirror.dc.uz/ubuntu/dists/jammy-security/main/binary-armhf/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.212.89.107 80]
E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.

Does it have anything to do with my Software & Updates settings? I looked other similar questions, but they didn't help.

Is your hardware actually armhf, or are you trying to add it as a foreign architecture? Most likely the mirror simply doesn't contain arm packages and you need to use ports.ubuntu.com instead - see for example How to fix a "Failed to fetch binary-armhf/Packages" error during apt-get update?

Adding armhf support with lines in /etc/apt/sources.list with lines like deb http://mirror.dc.uz/ubuntu jammy-security/restricted armhf is  not supported in Ubuntu 22.04. Maybe try installing the armhf packages in a Docker container instead.

Does that mirror provide PORTS architectures??  as most mirrors do not support the ports.  I don't see support here - https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+mirror/mirror.dc.uz-archive

I found out that my architecture is actually not armhf and I simply removed the armhf from foreign architectures and all the errors were gone. Thank all of you

Og'abek Samadov found out that his architecture was actually not armhf. He simply removed the armhf from foreign architectures, and all the errors were gone.
The armhf 32-bit architecture is not obsolete, but has been largely superseded by the arm64 (ARM 64-bit) architecture in many newer devices and applications.
